Finding the smallest time where an object enters the sphere of influence of a celestial body
I'm working on a 2D solar system simulation in Python using Keplerian elements. I am trying to find the earliest time (in seconds) where an object enters the sphere of influence (SOI) of a planet or a celestial body if there is an encounter with the SOI. But currently my method is not accurate and somehow always fails to find the nearest point that should be on the border of the sphere of influence. It only sometimes gives a point that is somewhere inside or entirely outside the sphere of influence but it is always on the orbit of the first object (obj). Is there anything wrong and how could i improve the method to solve for this encounter time? Here is the relevant portion of the code:
def search_for_encounter(obj, other_obj):

        def calculate_orbital_position_at_time(obj, dt):

            eccentricity = obj.eccentricity
            initial_mean_anomaly = obj.initial_mean_anomaly
            mean_motion = obj.mean_motion
            trajectory_type = obj.trajectory_type

            if trajectory_type == 0:
                # elliptic
                mean_anomaly = initial_mean_anomaly + mean_motion * dt
                eccentric_anomaly = Universe.calculate_eccentric_anomaly(eccentricity, mean_anomaly)
                true_anomaly = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(1 + eccentricity) * math.sin(eccentric_anomaly / 2), math.sqrt(1 - eccentricity) * math.cos(eccentric_anomaly / 2))

            elif trajectory_type == 1:
                # parabolic
                true_anomaly = 2 * math.atan((3 * mean_motion * dt / (2 * math.sqrt(obj.semi_latus_rectum))) ** (1 / 3))

            elif trajectory_type == 2:
                # hyperbolic
                mean_anomaly = initial_mean_anomaly + mean_motion * dt
                hyperbolic_anomaly = Universe.calculate_hyperbolic_anomaly(eccentricity, mean_anomaly)
                true_anomaly = 2 * math.atan(math.sqrt((eccentricity + 1) / (eccentricity - 1)) * math.tanh(hyperbolic_anomaly / 2))

            nu = true_anomaly
            p = obj.semi_latus_rectum
            i = obj.inclination
            Om = obj.longitude_of_ascending_node
            w = obj.argument_of_periapsis
            a = obj.semi_major_axis
            e = obj.eccentricity
            r = Universe.calculate_orbital_distance_out_of_elements(a, e, nu, p, trajectory_type)

            cos_Om = math.cos(Om)
            sin_Om = math.sin(Om)
            cos_i = math.cos(i)
            w_plus_nu = w + nu
            cos_w_plus_nu = math.cos(w_plus_nu)
            sin_w_plus_nu = math.sin(w_plus_nu)

            x = r * (cos_Om * cos_w_plus_nu - sin_Om * sin_w_plus_nu * cos_i)
            y = r * (sin_Om * cos_w_plus_nu + cos_Om * sin_w_plus_nu * cos_i)

            position = (x, y)
            return position

        def calculate_distance(t, obj, other_obj):
            obj_position = calculate_orbital_position_at_time(obj, t)
            other_obj_position = calculate_orbital_position_at_time(other_obj, t)
            relative_position = (obj_position[0] - other_obj_position[0], obj_position[1] - other_obj_position[1])
            distance = math.sqrt(relative_position[0] ** 2 + relative_position[1] ** 2) - other_obj.soi_radius
            return distance

        max_time_to_search = 1000000
        t0 = Universe.elapsed_seconds
        t1 = Universe.elapsed_seconds + max_time_to_search

        encounter_object = None
        encounter_time = None
        
        if other_obj is not obj.primary_body:
            try:
                result = minimize_scalar(
                        lambda t: calculate_distance(t, obj, other_obj),
                        bracket=[t0, t1],
                        method="brent"
                    )

                if result.success:
                    encounter_time = result.x
                    encounter_object = other_obj

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

        obj.encounter_point = calculate_orbital_position_at_time(obj, encounter_time) if encounter_time is not None else None
        return encounter_object, encounter_time


This question is tedious to answer as it stands, could use more concrete focus on what's going wrong. - Just as a remark, you're apparently building a patched conic approximation here. In case you didn't know that, it might be worth looking it up for references but also for general problems with that approach.

@Leonard Great! I ti s always OK to post an actual answer to your own question in Stack Exchange. In fact, it's encouraged so that future readers will see that an answer exists and the question is not unanswered.

Yes, i forgot to mention that i am using a patched conic approximation. But now i finally found the problem. When i calculate the position for the object without the sphere of influence, if there is an encounter, with the calculated time, i have not taken the last update time of the orbital elements of the object into account. It was a small mistake. So the method is actually working, but the minimize_scalar function is not optimal because it randomly selects one of the two points on the edge of the sphere of influence where the distance is nearly 0.
